# Eberron-like world for Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, game-recommendation, campaign-settings, eberron

I'm gonna GM a Pathfinder game in two months or so, and I'm looking for a setting like Eberron where I can set the story. I don't want an Adventure Path or a module series; I want a full setting that lets me develop my own campaign in it.

I'm specifically looking for a setting written to be Pathfinder-compatible, so Eberron itself doesn't qualify.

Comment: Have you considered... Eberron?

Comment: @mxyzplk Im looking for pathfinder only books and stuff

Comment: Can you tell us in detail what "Eberron-like" means to you?

Comment: And how Golarion doesn't qualify?

Comment: @Doppelgreener Are you certain about the last edit? Eberron material *was* published for [*Dungeons and Dragons 4E*](http://www.amazon.com/Eberron-Campaign-Guide-Roleplaying-Supplement/dp/0786950994/). Was it established in chat or comments that the asker is aware both that Eberron *D&D 3.5* material exists *and* that *Pathfinder* is nominally *D&D 3.5* compatible?

Comment: Oh that's a great point, I often forget 4e existed.  Summoner, you know Eberron started in 3.5e and has lots of 3.5e support right?

Comment: @HeyICanChan That's a fair point, I didn't even think of the 4e books - I thought the asker was dismissing the 3.5e books because they're not Pathfinder-specific.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## The Case for Eberron, Itself

Yeah, I know, no one’s ever written, or ever will write, an Eberron book for Pathfinder. That would be in violation of some copyright and trademark law (unless Wizards did it, but obviously they won’t).

But setting information doesn’t mind itself very much with mechanics. *Eberron Campaign Setting* has only a limited amount of new material:

- Action Points – can be used as is in Pathfinder
- Four new races – can be used as is, with the addition of a +2 to a single ability score.
- One new base class – this requires the most adjustment. More on this in a moment
- Various new feats – these can be used as-is excepting Legendary Artisan, which you can just pretend doesn’t exist. Does require the usual adjustments to skill rank requirements<sup>1</sup>
- Eight new prestige classes – these can be used as-is, with the usual adjustments to skill rank requirements<sup>1</sup>
- Myriad new spells and magic items – can be used as-is
- Several new monsters – usable as-is after calculating CMB/CMD

So, for the most part, what new mechanical material there *is*, can be used with a straightforward conversion. More importantly, mechanics only account for 57 pages of a 320-page book. Many other Eberron books have much lower percentages than that – *Dragonmarked*, *Explorer’s Handbook*, *Five Nations*, *Secrets of Sarlona*, and *Sharn, City of Towers* have very little mechanical material at all, it’s almost all description of people, places, and things in the world. Even the “crunchier” books, like *Faiths of Eberron*, *Magic of Eberron*, and *Secrets of Xen’drik*, have a ton of description that isn’t mechanical at all. That can all just be used as-is. And most of the mechanics require only straight-forward conversion.

But straight-forward conversion is still work. Plus, there’s the artificer, which definitely requires more consideration. That’s a pretty good reason to look for something else.

Or for [someone who has already done the work for you](http://pf-eberron.wikidot.com/). I was searching for good Pathfinder adaptations of the artificer when I found this website, and I’m quite impressed. They’ve done a very thorough job and the quality looks good. The big thing lacking from it is conversions of the monsters, and the artificer class.  But as far as explicitly-for-Pathfinder material that is Eberron-like, this looks like a wonderful resource.

So that leaves the artificer. There is a third-party class by that name on d20PFSRD.com; it’s very-poorly designed and I recommend against it. Instead, the artificer port that I recommend is [this one](https://steeldraco.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/artificer.pdf), which keeps much of the style and flavor of the artificer, in a more Pathfinder mode. It’s also somewhat better-balanced than Wizards’ own, though the Item Creation ability is always going to be potent. Personally, I would change this artificer back to being a full-list caster (i.e. simply knowing all the infusions on the list, rather than having to choose specific infusions known), though the style used by the arcanist would also fit well with the artificer style (and be more balanced than that class, thanks to the limit of 6th-level infusions).

---

<sup>1</sup> From [*Pathfinder Roleplaying Game Conversion Guide*](http://paizo.com/products/btpy89m6?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Conversion-Guide):

> #### Feats
>
> - If the feat refers to skills in any way, such as in the prerequisites or benefit line, make sure that the skill in question has not changed names or been removed from the game. If the feat requires that the character have a specific number of ranks in a particular skill, change that requirement to the listed number – 3 (minimum 1 rank).

> #### Prestige Classes
>
> - Make sure to check the prestige class requirements (and the rest of the class) for any skills that have been altered or removed from the game and adjust them accordingly. In addition, the skill rank requirements should be equal to the 3.5 requirements – 3 (minimum 1 rank).

Comment: +1 the system differences are so slight and the rules footprint on the setting so light there's no reason not just to up and use it.

Comment: Pathfinder's own [Hero Points](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/other-rules/hero-points) from the Advanced Player's Guide might be a good replacement for Action Points (Unless the latter are totally different than I remember).

Comment: @MrLemon Hero Points are far more potent than Action Points, and it’s important to the functioning of some Eberron feats that Action Points be an *X*/level thing, rather than gaining a variable number of them from DM rewards. Hero Points (from a brief skim) certainly seem thematically appropriate to an Eberron game, but they would be in addition to, rather than a replacement of, Action Points.